# Combination of two array formulas in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im new to this forum, so maybe I just didn't look well enough but I have a problem, which I haven't found the answer to yet.

I currently work with two array formulas, that work independently. These are:

```
INDEX(TEAMS!$B$3:$B$2000;SMALL(IF(TEAMS!$P$3:$P$2000=$G$11;ROW(TEAMS!$P$3:$P$2000)-ROW(TEAMS!$P$3)+1);ROWS($G$130:$G130)))
```

and

```
INDEX(UK!$D$28:$D$3948;SMALL(IF(UK!$L$28:$L$3948=$L$11;ROW(UK!$L$28:$L$3948)-ROW(UK!$L$28)+1);ROWS($L$130:$L130)))
```

The arrays they are referring to are located on two different sheets ('TEAMS' and 'UK'). Their purpose is to sort numbers which comply with certain criteria in the form of lowest to highest. The data in the arrays changes continually. When no data can be found in the arrays, I get the error message '#NUM', which I ignored as the data I receive is correct.

However, what I would now like to do is combine these formulas in one cell in such a way, that if formula 1 causes an error, formula 2 is displayed. IFERROR has not worked for me...

I'm no highly skilled Excel user... 
Maybe someone can help me? :)

Comment: how does the " IFERROR has not worked for me..." error message look like?

Comment: It also causes a '#NUM!' error saying it encountered arrows or circlar references. I entered it as follows: IFERROR(INDEX(UK!$D$28:$D$3948;SMALL(IF(UK!$L$28:$L$3948=$L$11;ROW(UK!$L$28:$L$3948)-ROW(UK!$L$28)+1);ROWS($L$130:$L130)));INDEX(TEAMS!$B$3:$B$2000;SMALL(IF(TEAMS!$P$3:$P$2000=$L$11;ROW(TEAMS!$P$3:$P$2000)-ROW(TEAMS!$P$3)+1);ROWS($L$130:$L130))))

Comment: check : is the formula is entered in the one of the range defined in both formula ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. What I want is if there is no (or no more) data matching the criteria in the one array, it should look in the second array for data matching the same criteria. So the index formula is the same, while the arrays should change. Is that what you meant?

Comment: erm.. what i mean is.. in which exactly is the formula is applied to ?

Comment: ah, sorry. No, the formula is no part of the two separate ranges. So the formula is applied to two different ranges on different worksheets.

Comment: @Bumbledoo 
it would be much better to give test data with the desired result

Comment: Since both formula "work independently" (which we, in SE cannot test).. then I don't see why you can't place them in 2 separate cells and do iferror() on it. | FYI circular error normally means there is a conflict of reference, in which if in any of the range defined (including the cell which this combined formula was entered) was actually referring to each other..  which in this case.. without a sample file/data we are unable to check/assist.

Comment: I have a testfile available. Can you tell me how I can share it? So sorry...

Comment: To share a test file, you must publish it to one of the public file services (Google Doc, One Drive, etc.) and add a link here. File must be accessible for everyone.